# Доступ к методам классов из других классов. Каждый класс в отдельном файле

Tags: c++, классы, компиляция

Есть три класса. Родительский `Figure` и два дочерних: `Line` и `Circle`. Каждому классу соответствует свой .cpp и .hpp файл.

*figure.hpp*

```
class Figure {
    virtual double length() = 0;
}
class Line;
class Circle;
```

*Line.hpp*

```
class Line : public Figure {
    std::vector<Point> intersection(Circle* circle);
}
```

*Circle.hpp*

```
class Circle : public Figure {
    std::vector<Point> intersection(Line* line);
}
```

*Line.cpp*

```
std::vector<Point> Line::intersection(Circle* circle) {
    return std::vector<Point>();
}
```

*Circle.cpp*

```
std::vector<Point> intersection(Line* line) {
    line->intersection(this);
}
```

IDE выдаёт сообщение об ошибке при вызове `line->intersection(this)`:

> Class 'Line' doesn't have function 'intersection'.

Как можно справиться с этим, не теряя модульности проекта? Потому что тривиальным решением было бы объявлять/реализовывать классы-наследники в одном файле.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете включить в Circle.cpp файл Line.hpp - это никак не нарушит вашу модульность, но `Circle` будет знать о наличии членов `Line`.

Но раз у вас `Circle` и `Line` по жизни пересекаются - о какой независимости и модульности можно говорить? :)

Comment: На самом деле, очень уместное замечание :) Но от меня требуются отдельные файлы для каждого класса - уж ничего не поделаешь

А правильно ли вообще так будет делать? Насколько я понимаю, тогда Line.hpp будет подключен дважды - изначально как наследник Figure и ещё раз, когда мы пишем `#include`

Comment: Вы подключаете его к реализации - это раз, а во-вторых, никто не отменял `#pragma once` или защиту от повторного включения c помощью define'ов (`if !defined(....) #define ....   текст   #endif`). Кстати, из ваших исходников нигде не следует, что это наследник `Figure`...

Comment: Спасибо, эта опечатка только здесь, исправил

Answer (score 1):

Модульность не подразумевает **полной** изоляции одного модуля от другого. Если в одном модуле требуется вызывать код другого модуля, то необходимо как минимум знать о наличии необходимых для вызова функций. Т.е. добавлением через `#include` определения одного класса (`*.h` файлов) без определения функций (`*.c` файлы) в другой файл, Вы как раз таки даете знать одному модулю о существовании другого. Другое дело, что функцию `intersection` можно было поместить вообще в базовый класс (несколько изменив сигнатуру, чтобы принимался `Figure*`), но в этом случае придется озаботиться решением проблемы двойной диспетчеризации.